# prototype extensions with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Using ember-cli and its ES6 module transpiler how and where would one define this so that would apply to all Arrays in my App:

```
Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
  ....
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Add a file to the `vendor/` directory with your extensions and include it in your `Brocfile.js` like so:

   ```
   app.import('vendor/my-prototype-extensions.js');
   ```
2. Do it in an initializer.

   ```
   ember g initializer extensions
   ```

   Then in `app/initializers/extension.js` add your extensions like so

   ```
   export var initialize = function() {
     Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
       ....
     };
   }

   export default {
     name: 'extensions',
     initialize: initialize
   }
   ```

I personally prefer the initializer approach as it's being done in the ember-cli ecosystem so you have access to anything available there if you need it.